# Powershell Script that references a text doc and moves everything NOT in that doc

Tags: powershell, file, copy, move, operation

I created a powershell script that copies the name of every file in a given folder (it creates filename.txt, not C:\path\filename.txt) and places it all in a text doc.

I'm now trying to write a powershell script that ONLY copies items to a different directory that are not contained in that text doc.

Any ideas? Thank you all.

Comment: You can start by looking at the `-Exclude` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` and put up some code to your question.

Comment: If you want to check the whole list of file names, then you might use the `-NotIn` operator like `$files | Where Name -NotIn $fileList | Copy-Item ...`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do exactly what you’re after in a more PowerShell way. Better to use an array to hold the names to be ignored. If you need to use the .txt then just use`Get-Content` to load the .txt into the `$ignoreFiles` variable.

```
#-file gets files only (not folders)
$ignoreFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\YOURS" -file).name
$checkFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\YOURS" -file
$targetFolder = "C:\Users\YOURS"
 
foreach ($t in $checkFolder){
    if($t.name -notin $ignoreFiles){
        Copy-Item $t.fullname $targetFolder
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error near the "-file).name" part in line 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Post the error?

Comment: "cannot bind argument to paramter because it is null"

Comment: Then one of your variables being passed to an argument is null. Likely a folder location that doesn’t exist. Use ISE debugger or simply run the previous lines in the console and see which variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
#-file gets files only (not folders)
$listPath = "\\server\C$\exclusionpath\list.txt"
$downloadPath = "\\adifferentserver\download\"
$targetFolder = "\\adifferentserver\Processing\"
$ignoreFiles = Get-Content -Path $listPath
$checkFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $downloadPath -File -Exclude $ignoreFiles - 
 Name
foreach ($t in $checkFolder){
#Copy-Item $t.fullname $targetFolder
Copy-Item (Get-ChildItem -Path $downloadPath -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 
$t}).FullName $targetFolder
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this solved your problem? Without an explanation it's unclear.